# In Infiniband, what mapping in PCIe-BAR, the internal buffer of Infiniband card or the remote computer's RAM?

Tags: c, memory-mapping, pci-e, infiniband, rdma

As we know, Infiniband allows RDMA - direct access to the memory of the remote computer.

It is also known, that the PCI-Express (endpoint) devices, including the PCIe-card Infiniband, are able to communicate in two ways:

- *IO Ports (in / out)* **deprecated**
- MMIO (BAR - memory mapped IO: mov)

But what exactly is displayed in the BAR (MMIO)? (when using PCIe-cards Infiniband):

- Its own internal buffer memory card Infiniband?
- part of RAM of a remote computer (the portion of RAM for which at the moment is copying data with RDMA)?

When I use Infiniband, what mapping in PCIe-BAR, the internal buffer of Infiniband card or the remote computer's RAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact contents and usage of the MMIO space for an HCA are going to be vendor- and maybe card-specific.  It does seem like it would be a simple approach to implementing RDMA to have the card and its driver set up an MMIO region directly corresponding to the remotely mapped memory.  However, thinking of that MMIO region as being one and the same as the remote memory is only true at a certain level of abstraction, probably at the [Infiniband verbs library](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~panda/788/papers/2c_VIG_SF.pdf&ei=l56PUqfjAcK9qwH66IHYAQ&usg=AFQjCNGTYaRoHUAm2eg-mFNVlPb7AHZ5LA&sig2=rsRwT0OtF2eUyp47yLRDBQ&bvm=bv.56988011,d.aWM) (pdf) layer or above.

Below that level, the protocol stack traversed by an RDMA write posted by an application on host A destined for host B will look something like:

1. Code executing on A does a mov into an MMIO address.
2. The memory management hardware on A's CPU socket recognizes the address as PCIe MMIO and
   sends the request either directly out of the CPU socket to PCIe if the HCA is plugged into the appropriate slot, or to the southbridge as a [DMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Media_Interface) packet or similar, and then in turn over PCIe to the HCA.
3. The HCA unwraps the RDMA payload from the PCIe packet and does whatever it needs to do to handle sending that information out to the Infiniband fabric.  Most likely this involves buffering the payload in some small memory on the HCA itself for a short time before sending the RDMA request out in an IB packet.

After traversing the IB fabric, the payload follows a roughly reverse series of steps on B:

1. B's HCA receives the IB packet and unwraps the payload.
2. The HCA possibly buffers the payload on the card itself for a short time while constructing a PCIe packet.
3. The PCIe packet traverses B's motherboard, possibly getting translated into DMI or other formats along the way, before arriving at B's DMA controller.
4. B's DMA controller arbitrates writing the payload to the region of B's system memory pinned for such RDMA transactions.

The key step that makes RDMA faster than competing technologies is B4.  Before any RDMA reads or writes took place, the Infiniband driver and verbs library on B set up a region of memory so that B's DMA controller would be able to safely write to it without any further context switches or OS or driver handling.  That means that besides whatever latency was added by the wire transmission (usually on the order of microseconds), processing by the receiving end adds very little latency to the transaction.  This step and the corresponding MMIO mapping on A also allow for zero-copy transfers, where neither side has to copy the memory of interest between kernel and user space to intermediate between the HCA, driver and application.

Here's a good link describing how this looks at a software level if you're calling IB verbs:

http://thegeekinthecorner.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/rdma-read-and-write-with-ib-verbs/

Comment: Big thanks! **1.** *"However, thinking of that MMIO region as being one and the same as the remote memory is only true at a certain level of abstraction, probably at the Infiniband verbs library (pdf) layer or above."* I.e. Can I use a simple instructions MOV (assembler) to write to MMIO region which mapped to user-space, and the data travels to remote server where Infiniband card will write the data to RAM using DMA-controller, or do I have to use (must) only special instructions `ibv_post_send()`?

Comment: **2.** *"1. Code executing on A does a mov into an MMIO address."* Does mapping to MMIO all remote memory, or just a small piece of it, or mapping only a small temporary buffer of Infiniband's card?

Comment: The answers to both questions are going to depend on the vendor, and I'm betting none of them publish the information you would need to do it at a lower level than ibv_post_send.  Internally, ibv_post_send or the driver call lying underneath it is probably doing something like a series of simple assembly MOVs into MMIO addresses.  I don't think that's guaranteed though, and based on my experience with other hardware companies, IB HCA vendors probably prefer not to publish exactly how they do it so that they have some flexibility to change how their drivers or the next rev of the card works.

Comment: I may have been wrong about the manufacturers not publishing how their devices work.  You might be able to find what you need by looking at the libibverbs source here: http://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/libibverbs/, an OpenFabrics driver like https://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/mlx4/ or the documentation at http://infiniband.sourceforge.net/.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

BAR's at a PCI/PCIe card must be initialized by the PnP subsystem of the OS (or BIOS) upon booting, so they should point to memory available long before the card is actually used. Threfore, that memory must be inside the card. The PCI controller then make these memory regions available to the address space of the CPU.

Comment: Thanks. But in run-time we can change translation of BARs (addresses from/to BAR mapped) through PCI-Express Configuration Space. Then can we do mapping remote RAM to the local physical address space?

Comment: Moreover, we are able to hot-swap or connect Infiniband already at runtime, that is, much later than the system booting.

Comment: Yes, hot-swapping allows post boot configuration, but even so, the BARs must be filled when the device is added to the system, and that happens bedore the device is actually used by a process to connect to a remote computer and start RDMA.

Comment: If I've understood well what RDMA means, and if it works the same way as regular DMA, then you don't need to have the remote memory available into your address space. RDMA is in charge to exchange blocks of memory between the two computers without CPU intervention (that's the role of a DMA controller). You always see your local memory, and if you need to read or write to remote memory, you do that by issuing RDMA requests.

Comment: *"what RDMA means, and if it works the same way as regular DMA"* - but for DMA we need to have mapped memory (an example mapped memory of any devices: ethernet, graphic card, etc...). And DMA-controller only copies data from CPU-RAM to the mapped buffer(GPU-RAM) of device by using system-addressing (or the same on x86 - bus-addressing). If we use temporary copying to the hardware buffer of Infiniband's card for each RDMA-packet, then it is already isn't zero-copy.